# Fix a div within a fixed div to prevent movement when scrolling

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have created a popup that appears and nearly fills the screen, and this popup is fixed so that it will remain centered on screen when the user scrolls the main page. But this popup is also scrollable and I have a header at the top of it that I want to always be visible.

How could I fix the header such that it will always be visible when the popup window is scrolled?

It seems if you set `position:fixed` this is always relative to the browser viewport, therefore it would be fixed to the top of the page not its parent container. Is this a task for sticky positioning in Webkit, or how can that be achieved?

[JSFiddle demonstrating the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/nmuk3cv6/) - scroll the blue popup and the yellow header scrolls away when I want that to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your CSS styling of `#header` to the following:

```
#header {
    position:fixed;
    width: inherit;
    height:2em;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nmuk3cv6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If your parent is having a position relative or absolute or fixed, then the child will position itself with respect to the parent element.

Add position:fixed to #header and padding-top:2em to make the text visible.

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:2em;
    padding-top:2em;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Here is the **Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/nmuk3cv6/3/